# Can't download Excel report from pivot view for large data

Tags: json, odoo, odoo-10

I can't download Excel Reports from pivot view when the data becomes large.
Its working fine in local and working fine in server while the data is small.

> Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
http://site/web#view_type=pivot&model=sale.report&action=287:1
Traceback:
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.<anonymous> (http://site/web/content/4129-cba42b2/web.assets_common.js:3038:379)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.dispatch (http://site/web/content/4129-cba42b2/web.assets_common.js:637:451)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.elemData.handle (http://site/web/content/4129-cba42b2/web.assets_common.js:610:173)
```

Comment: Update the configuration file on server and increase the value of `limit_time_real` parameter. This will help you :)

Comment: `limit_time_real` not found @PyMaster .. What to do ?

Comment: Odoo server configuration file has this parameter. If you don't find it in file then add this parameter in it. For further reference on configuration please check the documentation of odoo. http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/cmdline.html

Comment: limit_time_real  does not fix the issue for me